# Averaging certain values in Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in Python that looks like this:

```
  Acct_Num  Acct_Bal             Acct_Type  Acct_Rate    Cust_ID  Emp_ID
0  13330001    2020.0  Check                     0.010  111223333  223333
1  17890006      50.0  Check                     0.010  224422444  223333
2  23330004    3550.0  Saving                    0.030  224422444  223333
3  23330007   11000.0  Saving                    0.035  111223333  223333
4  27890002     130.0  Saving                    0.030  987654321  456789
5  27890003     299.0  Saving                    0.035  123123123  456789
6  37890005   10999.0  Money                     0.040  111223333  456789
7  41230008  200323.0  Loan                      0.070  224422444  123123
8  41230009   21789.0  Loan                      0.075  224422444  123123
9  41230010    1000.0  Loan                      0.060  987654321  123123
```

I need to find the average Acct_Rate where the Acct_Type is "Loan". I know I can find the average of the entire column using `df['Acct_Rate'].mean()` but I can't figure out how to do it for only Loan account types. Please help, thank you. If you could also show me how to do it in SQL terms that would be great. Cheers!

Comment: could you share what your expected output would be. Do you want a single value of the loan account rates? do you want it in a separate column? The output format dictates how the solution in written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter a dataframe, you can pass in a bool index. For instance, to get only the rows where `Acct_Type` is `Loan`, one could write

```
df[df.Acct_Type == 'Loan']
```

Extending your attempt with this, it is possible to get the mean of `Acct_Rate` given `Acct_type == 'Loan'` as follows:

```
df[df.Acct_Type == 'Loan'].Acct_Rate.mean()
```

In SQL, this would take the following form

```
select avg(acct_rate) from mytable where acct_type = 'Loan'
```